# Chip Off the Old Block

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Born in the 70s, I'm everywhere today. 
>   I start as real but get in people's way. 
>   After generations, I still remember my roots. 
>   Look closely, you'll find biology in my boots. 
>   When I'm protected I perform at my best. 
>   You'll see me with flags after a test. 
>   For purists I offer no charm. 
>   I have an eye but no arm.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it

> An Intel x86 processor

Born in the 70s, I'm everywhere today.

> The first x86 chip, the 8086, was introduced in 1978.

I start as real but get in people's way.

> The 286 architecture introduced protected mode, but they still booted in real mode for compatibility reasons.

After generations, I still remember my roots.

> Each new processor design was referred to as a generation, but they remain backward compatible with the earlier generations

Look closely, you'll find biology in my boots.

> The computer boots from a BIOS, which contains the word Bio

When I'm protected I perform at my best.

> Protected mode enables features like virtual memory and paging, which are pretty important in a modern computer

You'll see me with flags after a test.

> The FLAGS register is the status register in Intel chips, and the TEST assembly instruction results in 3 flags being modified.

For purists I offer no charm.

> A purist might prefer a RISC architecture

I have an eye but no arm.

> Intel begins with an I, and ARM are a competitor.

Comment: @qwr / jsm - they kinda do, feel free to clean 'em up now that you've both seen them

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a Macintosh

Born in the 70s, I'm everywhere today.

> Apple was created in 1976 and now it's products are everywhere

I start as real but get in people's way.

> the older Mac are useless now

After generations, I still remember my roots.

> Apple products keep the same names generations after generations

Look closely, you'll find biology in my boots.

> older versions of MacOS X used animals as codenames

When I'm protected I perform at my best.

> viruses are not fun and apple products are no exception

You'll see me with flags after a test.

> in programming flags are used to indicate that a certain event has taken place and are useful when you want to test something

For purists I offer no charm.

> some might say that linux is better

I have an eye but no arm.

> there is an "I" at the begining of "iMac" but they don't use ARM processors (for now)

Comment: Close but the "real" "biology" "flag test" "protected" clues are a stretch.

Comment: Also these were introduced in 1984.